# Check the form input value to existing value in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In in my database there are some emails those should be checked with the form value which is entered in email field

`models.py`

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

`forms.py`

```
class FriendForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Friend
        fields = ['email']
```

`views.py`

```
def check(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        form = FriendForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            queryset = Friend.objects.all
            return render(request,"two.html",{"queryset":queryset})
     else:
        form = FriendForm()
    return render(request, 'emaill.html', {'form': form})
```

`emaill.html`

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
 </body>
```

`two.html`

```
<body>
 <h1>found</h1>
 {% for obj in queryset %}
 {{obj.email}} </br>
 {% endfor %}
</body>
```

when user submited any email that should be checked with models email that means with existing one if matches in should render to two.html it should show connect
if mail does not match with mail that is in database it should show no such mail

Comment: Dileep, do you mean you to avoid having an email registered twice. Whatever you are doing you are doing it poorly. Why are you interested in displaying emails present.  The best choice would be via form validation. You should be a little more patient please the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: the output should be in the email field if i entered some email . this email should be check with the database if both matches it should render to two,html and show connected

Comment: I have seen that, just interested in knowing why you want to display the emails back to the user. If it already exists.

Comment: actually user enters some  random or any email if this email exist in database then it should be show a option to connect them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I understand what you are trying to do. You are doing an email search.

```
def check(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FriendForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data("email")
            try:
                 friend = Friend.objects.get(email=email)
                 return render(request,"email1.html",
                       {"friend":friend})
            except Friend.DoesNotExist:
                return render(request, "email1.html", {"form":form})
```

If you are interested in connecting them, then you should use the get method of the ModelManager (objects). That will return a single object if it exists. 
In your template. As you can see I have saved some typing on an extra template by using conditions in the template.

```
{% if form %}
  #display your form
{% else %}
  #display the friend as you want
{% endif %}
```

I recommend you go slow and do more reading of the documentation. I am here. Note that I changed your queryset to friend. queryset is misleading as it points that you want multiple objects. So in your template you cant iterate, instead you display friend without iterating.

```
{{ friend }}
```